# Is it possible to get SQL Injection if PreparedStatement is used without setString?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Let's say if I am using PreparedStatement and passing user-inputs directly to it. Can it cause SQLi ?

I looked other stackoverflow answers, but none explains this

For example

```
String q = '%' + request.getParameter("search") + '%';
PreparedStatement s = s("SELECT * FROM table_name where search="+q);
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery();
```

In this case, as we can see there is no `?` or `setString` used. Can such code cause SQLI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An attacker can set the search parameter to something like `; DELETE FROM users;`. Your prepared statement call has no way of knowing that the SQL you pass to it isn't something you intend to run, since you build the string before the call.

Answer (score 0):

*Any time* you concatenate user-supplied strings to build a SQL statement, without adequately escaping the string, you're susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.

Your code should be written like this:

```
String search = request.getParameter("search");

String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE search LIKE ?";
try (PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    s.setString(1, '%' + search + '%');
    try (ResultSet r = s.executeQuery()) {
        // more code here
    }
}
```

Notice the use of `LIKE` to get the wildcards to work right, and the use of try-with-resources to correctly `close()` the JDBC resources.